# OpenStreetMaps - tiles - performance concerns for heavy usage

Tags: google-maps, leaflet, bing-maps, openstreetmap

I am working on a mobile app that is going to be mainly map-based. I am new to map-development. Mostly my app will be using Markers and some Custom controls to allow users to go to some page/pop-up for showing some details/links to other functionality. Its NOT going to use navigation or 'search nearby' or places features. But the maps view will be the main view for the users (something like 'waze' app, whose main functionality is on the 'Maps' view). So I am expecting some heavy traffic on my maps view.

Because Google starts charging for apps after the threshold, I am planning to use the open-source Map API - leaflet. and tiles from openStreetMap. http://www.openstreetmap.org/

My question is, if my user base rises (like waze has around 2.6 million users), should I be concerned about the openStreetMap tiles scaling up to that heavy traffic. Would it scale up nicely or will it give performance issues.?

While I am trying to get in touch with OSM with my above question, I thought of putting this question here also at SO, will appreciate if the map developers can share their experiences of using this API-Tile combo and/or if you have any other recommendations/suggestions/advice in regards to maps development.

Comment: You say you've asked OSM but i can't seem to find your question @ [https://help.openstreetmap.org](https://help.openstreetmap.org), a link would be helpful. They have a very active community so i'm kinda curious as to what they have to say.

Comment: I haven't posted my question there on OSM yet, I got involved in some more reading. Also I hoped the answers here will make me better prepared and more informed to ask a question there in terms of my understanding of how tiles usage/request work. And I believe the below answer from yarl is pointing me in the right direction for what I needed. I am still doing some more study before I accept one of the below answers, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have official OSM [tile usage policy](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy). You might also take a look at [list of OSM tile-hosting providers](http://switch2osm.org/providers/).

Comment: In other words: You are not allowed to use the official OSM tile servers for heavy traffic because they run on donated resources. Instead create [your own tile server](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/) or use on of the paid providers.

Comment: yes, I understood that after reading the OSM tiles usage policy that @yarl gave a link to, thats why I accepted this answer, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Use Bing Maps, they have a [limit of 50,000 transactions for 24 hours](https://www.microsoft.com/maps/Licensing/licensing.aspx), I doubt if even waze have so many in the US).

Comment: thanks, maybe I am lacking some basic understanding here. If my app users go above 50000, lets say to 100000, and lets say if a user visits my map page twice/day on an average, I am already at 4 times above that limit (or is there any caching mechanism playing here per device?) And I am trying to understand why waze may not have that many users in US. I believe I am missing something here.

Comment: It will take a long time for your app to exceed the 50,000 transaction limits. There are a lot of big name apps using Bing Maps that are not exceeding these limits.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be fine with OSM tiles to begin with. If you end up with a very large number of users, you might want to look at [Mapbox](http://www.mapbox.com/), which are competitively priced compared to Google Maps, since for example Foursquare and Airbnb switched from Google Maps to Leaflet and Mapbox. They also have very good looking maps, and most of their tools are open source.

Comment: thanks Liedman, like I said in comment to Geremy's anaswer, I'm really lacking some very basic understanding of transactions/map views usage.As mentioned in Mapbox plans, 15 tiles=1 mapview. If my one app user is swiping back and forth ,up and down, that means lot more tiles request than just 15. Their premium plan is $499/month that gives 1,000,000 mapviews/month, which I believe will be very less if we think of monthly usage of the app by a larger user-base. I'll appreciate if you can point me to some resources to clear my understanding of mapviews/transactions.

Comment: @Liedman That's wrong. The official OSM tile servers are not suited for heavy traffic, they run on donated resources.

Comment: @scai yeah, my point was that very few sites have to deal with heavy load from day one. Good to have a plan for tiles if the site takes off, but OSM tile server performance is likely to be the least of your scaling problems.

Comment: @kkap I think you should talk to Mapbox, I'm pretty sure they can help you get some sensible numbers for costs. Also, as I mentioned above, don't give *too* much energy to what will happen if you have millions of users. Very few sites will gather a million users, and even if they do, they usually have years to adapt to the growing user base.